# Proceso Terminado con el codigo 1 en la terminal apenas entro a WSL

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, wsl

Cada vez que ingreso a la terminal de WSL me manda este creo que error, hay una forma de solucionarlo?, antes de que me sucediera este error yo ya habia instalado zsh

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seguiste esta guia de instalacion? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
lo mas importante es tener el windows preview, instalar el update de wsl, activar la funcion de windows para subsistema de linux

Comment: si lo seguí, despues intente instalar zsh y no me funciono

Comment: disculpa, pero la instalacion de wsl2 no requiere en ningun mometno de zsh

Answer (score 1):

Abre **Windows PowerShell** como administrador y escribe `netsh winsock reset`, pulsa **Enter**, luego reinicia el equipo.